# Pine Script - variable store and changes

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Having trouble converting a defined signal into variable from which i can use to count how many bars since the last time conditions were meet making the signal true.

For instance if i have:
`longsignal = close > ta.sma(50, close)`

and assume i got out of the trade but want to wait until close falls below the SMA50 before going in again.  So i need to store when longsignal was last met and also when close most recently went below SMA50 so I can add an additional condition to 'longsignal' to say that it must also be true that a crossover defined as 'close < SMA50' occurred in time more recently than the most recent 'longsignal'.  Additionally i need a starting argument to get things going since the first trade will have no 'long signal' to reference

i tried creating var for each but all my arguments seem to fail to be complete

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ta.barssince()` function to count the number of bars since the last time the condition was true.

```
since_longsignal = ta.barssince(longsignal)
```

You can also use `ta.crossover(close, sma50)`. It will only be true if the price comes below sma50 and closes over sma50.

Comment: thank you.  But i then get 'undeclared identifier 'longsignal'.  I suspect because i have not stored the data as to such event occurring. how do i address that?

Comment: You need to define your condition `longsignal` before that line.

Comment: apology - you are being crazy helpful and i am being obtuse in my explaining.  the set up is my 'longsignal' is based on a percentage change from a pivot low.  BUT once I am out of that trade it wants to go right back in if indeed the close after i get out remains above the % above the pivot low as a new pivot may not have been created yet. So I want to stop it from trading again until there has been a new pivot.  this is why i was trying to drive the 'longsignal' to also be depending upon their having been one in closer proximity in time to the last pivot.